# How can I sort excel sheets/tabs in workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to sort the tabs/sheets in a workbook alpha- numerically. I am using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) to manipulate the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to sort the `workbook._sheets` list.

```
workbook._sheets = sorted(workbook._sheets)
```

This may result in the active worksheet (referred to by an index) to change silently so the sorting operation should be followed by something like `workbook.active = 0`.

I would try it first with test data as the direct access to the so-called "private" `_sheets` attribute might mess things up and corrupt your data.

As per the comment by Charlie Clark below, using so-called "private" attributes can compromise the way a module is working. If you want to make it proper read the source thoroughly to understand what it involves and subclass the `Workbook` class to add a new method that does the sorting.

... and bear in mind that updating `openpyxl` might result in your finely crafted subclass not working anymore. You may suggest to include the sorting method into the `openpyxl` code so that it is maintained adequately.

Python will not forbid you to turn your computer into a disobedient monster as long as it is what you fancy.

> We are all consenting adults here.
>
> *Guido von Rossum*

Comment: While this won't affect worksheets themselves, it is inadvisable to recommend using private attributes.