# Sort tabs in XLSX workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am not sure if I should or should not create a new question because the accepted answer doesn't work.  Please advise.  Do I just reply to that same question as an answer?  Here is the same question: [How can I sort excel sheets/tabs in workbook using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681005/how-can-i-sort-excel-sheets-tabs-in-workbook-using-openpyxl).  I am not sure if it doesn't work due to a user issue (usually is) or to an older/newer version of openpyxl.

Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws1 = wb.create_sheet("B")
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("A")
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("C")
ws4 = wb.create_sheet("D")

wb._sheets = sorted(wb._sheets) #Error comes up at this line

wb.save('test_tabs.xlsx')
```

I received the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Worksheet' and 'Worksheet'
```

Therefore, I tried to manually sort the list of sheets:

```
>>> type(wb._sheets)
<class 'list'>

>>> wb._sheets
[<Worksheet "Sheet">, <Worksheet "B">, <Worksheet "A">, <Worksheet "C">, <Worksheet "D">]

>>> wb._sheets = [<Worksheet "A">, <Worksheet "B">, <Worksheet "C">, <Worksheet "D">, <Worksheet "Sheet">]
File "<stdin>", line 1

# Manual sort of sheets
wb._sheets = [<Worksheet "A">, <Worksheet "B">, <Worksheet "C">, <Worksheet "D">, <Worksheet "Sheet">]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I noticed that the list items are not not enclosed by `'` or `"` so I am wondering if `sort` is failing because of that.

And, for kicks, I tried adding `'` to the list items:

```
wb._sheets = ['<Worksheet "A">', '<Worksheet "B">', '<Worksheet "C">', '<Worksheet "D">', '<Worksheet "Sheet">']

>>> wb._sheets
['<Worksheet "A">', '<Worksheet "B">', '<Worksheet "C">', '<Worksheet  "D">', '<Worksheet "Sheet">']

>>> wb.save('test_tabs2.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
....
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sheet_state'

>>> openpyxl.__version__
'2.4.1'
```

Comment: You need to provide a sort key and sort the actual worksheets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution, `sort`ing on `ws.title`, works for me:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws1 = wb.create_sheet("B")
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("A")
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("C")
ws4 = wb.create_sheet("D")

wb._sheets.sort(key=lambda ws: ws.title)

wb.save('test_tabs.xlsx')
```

Result:

[image]